# Home screen bottom bar buttons

Tags: home-screen, launcher

I don't understand why the Android 2.3 SDK docs show the home screen dock as beeing this:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fc/Google_Nexus_S_smartphone.jpg

And I have this, unchanged from 2.1 to 2.3.4 now:
http://blog.nimbuzz.com/files/2010/06/samsung-galaxy-s-android-launches-2.jpg

Is it a Samsung thing?
Is there an `official` launcher for 2.3 and the `Samsung` one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, yes. That's Samsung's UI/framework, [TouchWiz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TouchWiz). Other manufacturers have their own UIs as well, including HTC's [Sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Sense) and Motorola's [Motoblur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motoblur). The Nexus S has the "stock" Android UI.

Comment: Aaa, so that's where `TWLauncher` comes from. OK. Is there anyway to get the "stock" launcher as an installable app rather than mess with the firmware?

Comment: @Francisc: There seem to be versions of it on the Market, but I don't know much about them, personally (never used them). [Here's a quick search](https://market.android.com/search?q=gingerbread+launcher&so=1&c=apps) that has a few, though, and also looks to have some themes for other launchers (like ADW) that make it look like the stock GB one. I wouldn't be surprised if there's an .apk version floating around on [XDA](http://www.xda-developers.com/), too.

Comment: I searched the market, none looks reliable. But the XDA suggestion is good. As long as it doesn't require rooting, I'll give it a go. Thank you, appreciate it.